# How can i make Redis and Mysql work together with a hosting provider?

Tags: mysql, redis, nosql, hosting

I have an application which use Redis and Mysql together, but I can't find an hosting plan which can make them work together, I find only plan only for mysql or plan for redis and other nosql databases, how I have to move to make my project work out of the local server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install Redis on your server and use it.

[refer this link to install](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04)